# How to prevent unwanted tooltip pop-up in Infragistics ComboBoxTool on ribbon control (winforms)

Tags: winforms, tooltip, infragistics

I have a ComboBoxTool on an UltraToolbarsManager implementing a ribbon control. No matter what I set the ToolTipText to it always displays a tooltip:

[image]

[e.g. mousing over the gdg combo show this]

I have tried setting all the other tooltip related attributes (ToolTipTextFormatted, ToolTipTitle) to null but this doesn't help.

- If a non-zero length tooltip text is specified then this shows as expected
- The ribbon child controls are all added programatically
- The other controls on the ribbon do not have this issue

I have also tried setting-up a very simple ribbon on a dummy project and that does not exhibit this strange behaviour. So it is something else that is effecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infragistics supplied an answer:

1. Add your own CreationFilter to the ToolbarsManager

   ultraToolbarsManager1.CreationFilter = new MyCreation();
2. Catch the tool creation and replace the tooltip with your own implementation

   ```
   public class MyCreation : IUIElementCreationFilter  {

       private readonly int max;

       public MyCreation()
       {
       }

       public MyCreation(int toolTipMaxWidth)
       {
           max = toolTipMaxWidth;
       }

       public void AfterCreateChildElements(UIElement parent)
       {
           parent.ToolTipItem = new MyToolTipItem(max);
       }

       public bool BeforeCreateChildElements(UIElement parent)
       {
           return false;
       }
   }


   public class MyToolTipItem : IToolTipItem   {
       private readonly int max;

       public MyToolTipItem(int maxWidth)
       {
           max = maxWidth;
       }

       public MyToolTipItem()
       {
       }

       public ToolTipInfo GetToolTipInfo(Point mousePosition, UIElement element, UIElement previousToolTipElement,
                                     ToolTipInfo toolTipInfoDefault)
       {
           // set tooltip info for ribbon ApplicationMenuButton
           var app = element as ApplicationMenuButtonUIElement;
           if (app != null)
           {
               var appmenu = ((UltraToolbarsDockAreaUIElement) ((app.Parent).Parent)).ToolbarsManager.Ribbon.ApplicationMenu;
               if (max > 0)
                   toolTipInfoDefault.MaxWidth = max;
               toolTipInfoDefault.Title = appmenu.ToolTipTitle;

               string tooltiptex = appmenu.ToolTipText;
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(appmenu.ToolTipTextFormatted))
               {
                   toolTipInfoDefault.ToolTipTextStyle = ToolTipTextStyle.Formatted;
                   tooltiptex = appmenu.ToolTipTextFormatted;
               }
               toolTipInfoDefault.ToolTipText = tooltiptex;
           }

           // set tooltip info for tools
           if (element.ToolTipItem != null && UIElement.IsContextOfType(element.GetContext(), typeof (ToolBase)))
           {
               var tool = (ToolBase) element.GetContext(typeof (ToolBase));
               var loc = tool.ToolbarsManager.DockWithinContainer.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));
           loc.Offset(tool.UIElement.Rect.Location.X, 185);

               if (max > 0)
                   toolTipInfoDefault.MaxWidth = max;
           toolTipInfoDefault.Title = tool.SharedProps.ToolTipTitle;
           string tooltiptex = tool.SharedProps.ToolTipText;
               if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tool.SharedProps.ToolTipTextFormatted))
               {
                   toolTipInfoDefault.ToolTipTextStyle = ToolTipTextStyle.Formatted;
                   tooltiptex = tool.SharedProps.ToolTipTextFormatted;
               }
               toolTipInfoDefault.ToolTipText = tooltiptex;
               toolTipInfoDefault.DisplayStyle = Infragistics.Win.ToolTipDisplayStyle.Office2007;
               toolTipInfoDefault.Location = loc;
           }
           return toolTipInfoDefault;
       }
   ```

Required a bit of tweaking to get the tooltip in the right place and pick-up the tooltip text from TooltipTextResolved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be a bug. You should probably submit it to Infragistics.

If you don't want any tool tips displaying for the entire ribbon group, you can set the RibbonGroup.Settings.ShowToolTips value to False. In fact, if you want to turn off tool tips on a wider scale, you can set one of the following properties to False instead:

- RibbonTab.GroupSettings.ShowToolTips
- ContextualTabGroup.GroupSettings.ShowToolTips
- Ribbon.GroupSettings.ShowToolTips
- UltraToolbarsManager.ShowToolTips

Each property will turn off tool tips for all tool instances within the associated container.

But if you only want to turn of tool tips for this one tool, you can use a tool that derives from ComboBoxTool. In your derived tool, you can override ShouldDisplayToolTip and you can return False.

Comment: Thanks I'll get in contact with Infragistics and report back